# Data I can encode in QR code

Tags: php, qr-code

I have an index.php page and a dashboard.php page. After entering credentials, user logs into the dashboard.php.

Now i want to display a QR code which can be used by the user to directly log into dashboard.php using his phone.

This can be achieved if I somehow encode the session values in the QR code. But is it possible to do so? I have only managed to store the url of the page to index.php

Comment: I'm not sure if it is desirable to do so. Keep in mind that it is easy for others to scan the code too. they can "hijack" the session this way

Comment: Yes but I am planning to get the device registered somehow. So that only user can login through his device

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `QRcode class` to achieve what you want..
may be below links can help you out..

http://qrcodescript.com/

http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-qr-codes-in-php/

http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you're showing the QR to a user that has logged in, you can use the session hash and encode it in the QR code you show to the user as a GET parameter (site.com/qrlogin.php?code=123456). The session data needs to be on the server (so no cookies, no local storage, etc...). This is used if you want the user to log in using the phone **while** he's also logged in from a computer. Pretty harmless.

However, if you want a more permanent solution, there is nothing you can do that won't pose a security threat (the app has no way of knowing who scanned the code).

Comment: Completely agreed. I am looking for a more elegant solution to fix such a threat. Probably have a phone registered on the website and if the user log in through, it can be verified.